# Какие есть ограничения на правку описания меток/тегов?

Tags: обсуждение

В последнее время я занялся исправление ошибок в метках (опечатки и т.п.).
После правки нескольких меток я не имел возможности новые править, пока не будут приняты (или отвергнуты) исправленные мной.

Прошла половина суток, а править до сих пор не могу, а таких еще много.

Как можно узнать: когда возможно продолжить редактирование других меток?

---

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: система должна писать, сколько времени тебе надо отдохнуть от правок.

Comment: Добавил скрин в вопрос

Comment: Проблема в том, что отсутствует кнопка "Редактировать описание метки"?

Comment: Угу, исчезла она, а когда появится вновь и не ясно :)

Comment: Не забывайте добавлять ник через @ в комментарии. А то оповещение не приходит.

Comment: @alexolut, забыл уже, давно с комментаторами здесь не общался :)

Answer (score 2):

Система автоматически заблокировала вам правки меток на 7 дней, т.к. у вас было [много отклоненных правок за последние сутки](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/201445/gil9red?tab=activity&sort=suggestions).

А причиной отклонения правок среди прочего послужил [плагиат](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/146308) с Википедии.

Comment: Где-то это должно быть видно автору правок или только модератор знает?

Comment: @alexolut сомневаюсь, что это где-то видно, поэтому сам отправляю письмо участнику в таких случаях, если инициатором отклоненных правок был я. Или кто-то мне об этом рассказал.

Comment: Ну не плагиат, и не с вики, а отсюда ( https://uchil.net/?cm=48014) насколько я помню. А там вроде бы не было ничего про лицензию, хотя вики повторяет (тем более не полностью). Так то, я старался из вики если и брать, то перефразировать

Comment: Куда мне если я не согласен с отклонение правки? Например: "веб-сервисов на на удалённых компьютерах" -> "веб-сервисов на удалённых компьютерах". Кое-кто из модераторов видимо считает что чем больше "на", тем убедильнее будет описание. Или то, что неправильное описание семантики маллока нормально: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/146499 . Описание ведь должно быть правильным не только с зрения смысла, но и с грамматики/орфографии и опечаткам не место. С маллоком завернули потому что пропустил предыдущий аргумент `n`

Comment: @gil9red я пропустил эту правку. Но на мой взгляд не стоит в malloc пихать С++. В С++ есть new. malloc - для совместимости с С. Этого уже достаточно чтобы отклонить правку.

Comment: @gil9red С "на на" я тоже не согласен и сразу поправил.

Comment: @Nofate Бари Алибасова на Вас нет!

Comment: *А там вроде бы не было ничего про лицензию* - отсутствие явной лицензии в тексте сайта - это всегда копирайт.

Comment: Обсудить правки можно, например, в чате: [chat]. Или на Мете. В целом улучшение орфографии я только поддерживаю. Но как и всегда: пока ваши правки премодерируются - они не должны быть тривиальными.

Comment: @pavel, официальная документация с++ с вами не согласится: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/malloc/ . Нельзя ведь сказать что маллок к с++ не относится, поэтому отклонять правку не считаю правильным

Comment: Nofate, как тогда правильно сделать? Ждать неделю до разблокировки, в чате собирать тех, у кого хватит репутации для подтверждения правки, объяснять им почему так нужно исправить, и... править? Такое отобъет желание помогать. Ладно бы были просто случаи отклонения -- хорошо, всем не угодишь, а блокировка просто чудовищна. Я ведь не ддос атаку устроил и ботами правил, а руками и большим таймаутом

Comment: @gil9red, блокировку я смог снять. Но обсудить спорные правки все же стоит.